# TypeError: Cannot read property 'populate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Mongoose перестал обрабатывать ".populate", выдает ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read property 'populate' of undefined.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"connect-mongodb-session": "^2.2.1",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.16.1",
"mongoose": "^5.5.3",
"uuid": "^3.3.2"
```

}

Models/

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: Number,
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
})
```

App.js

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await req.user
  .populate('cart.items.itemId')
  .execPopulate()

  res.render('cart')
})
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Из-за обновления версии mongoose?

Comment: в `req.user` ничего нет

Comment: Cвязано ли это с установкой session и хранения их в mongo?  До установки, все работало.

Comment: вы ведь можете это проверить?

Comment: Как я понял, после подключения session, req.user уже не был связан с mongoose. Поэтому он и выводил ошибку. Благодарю за ответ!